# ImportError: No module named 'models.flownet2_pytorch'

Tags: python, deep-learning

I'm new to DL & using Nvidia Server
Trying to run vid2vid and
already followed the instructions here:
https://github.com/NVIDIA/vid2vid

It seems like I got error about 'models.flownet2_pytorch'
I followed the installation here:
https://github.com/NVIDIA/flownet2-pytorch/blob/master/README.md#convert-official-caffe-pre-trained-models-to-pytorch

However I get the error
 ------------ Options -------------

```
add_face_disc: False
aspect_ratio: 1.0
basic_point_only: False
batchSize: 1
checkpoints_dir: ./checkpoints
dataroot: datasets/Cityscapes/
dataset_mode: temporal
debug: False
densepose_only: False
display_id: 0
display_winsize: 512
feat_num: 3
fg: True
fg_labels: [26]
fineSize: 512
gpu_ids: [0]
how_many: 300
input_nc: 3
isTrain: False
label_feat: False
label_nc: 35
loadSize: 2048
load_features: False
load_pretrain: 
max_dataset_size: inf
model: vid2vid
nThreads: 2
n_blocks: 9
n_blocks_local: 3
n_downsample_E: 3
n_downsample_G: 3
n_frames_G: 3
n_gpus_gen: 1
n_local_enhancers: 1
n_scales_spatial: 3
name: label2city_2048
ndf: 64
nef: 32
netE: simple
netG: composite
ngf: 128
no_canny_edge: False
no_dist_map: False
no_first_img: False
no_flip: False
no_flow: False
norm: batch
ntest: inf
openpose_only: False
output_nc: 3
phase: test
random_drop_prob: 0.05
random_scale_points: False
remove_face_labels: False
resize_or_crop: scaleWidth
results_dir: ./results/
serial_batches: False
start_frame: 0
tf_log: False
use_instance: True
use_real_img: False
use_single_G: True
which_epoch: latest
-------------- End ----------------

CustomDatasetDataLoader
dataset [TestDataset] was created
vid2vid
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 25, in <module>
    model = create_model(opt)
  File "/workspace/AI/vid2vid/models/models.py", line 7, in create_model
    from .vid2vid_model_G import Vid2VidModelG
  File "/workspace/AI/vid2vid/models/vid2vid_model_G.py", line 13, in <module>
    from . import networks
  File "/workspace/AI/vid2vid/models/networks.py", line 12, in <module>
    from .flownet2_pytorch.networks.resample2d_package.resample2d import Resample2d
**ImportError: No module named 'models.flownet2_pytorch'**
```

the packages installed on my server are

```
add_face_disc: False
aspect_ratio: 1.0
basic_point_only: False
batchSize: 1
checkpoints_dir: ./checkpoints
dataroot: datasets/Cityscapes/
dataset_mode: temporal
debug: False
densepose_only: False
display_id: 0
display_winsize: 512
feat_num: 3
fg: True
fg_labels: [26]
fineSize: 512
gpu_ids: [0]
how_many: 300
input_nc: 3
isTrain: False
label_feat: False
label_nc: 35
loadSize: 2048
load_features: False
load_pretrain: 
max_dataset_size: inf
model: vid2vid
nThreads: 2
n_blocks: 9
n_blocks_local: 3
n_downsample_E: 3
n_downsample_G: 3
n_frames_G: 3
n_gpus_gen: 1
n_local_enhancers: 1
n_scales_spatial: 3
name: label2city_2048
ndf: 64
nef: 32
netE: simple
netG: composite
ngf: 128
no_canny_edge: False
no_dist_map: False
no_first_img: False
no_flip: False
no_flow: False
norm: batch
ntest: inf
openpose_only: False
output_nc: 3
phase: test
random_drop_prob: 0.05
random_scale_points: False
remove_face_labels: False
resize_or_crop: scaleWidth
results_dir: ./results/
serial_batches: False
start_frame: 0
tf_log: False
use_instance: True
use_real_img: False
use_single_G: True
which_epoch: latest
-------------- End ----------------
CustomDatasetDataLoader
dataset [TestDataset] was created
vid2vid
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 25, in <module>
    model = create_model(opt)
  File "/workspace/AI/vid2vid/models/models.py", line 7, in create_model
    from .vid2vid_model_G import Vid2VidModelG
  File "/workspace/AI/vid2vid/models/vid2vid_model_G.py", line 13, in <module>
    from . import networks
  File "/workspace/AI/vid2vid/models/networks.py", line 12, in <module>
    from .flownet2_pytorch.networks.resample2d_package.resample2d import Resample2d
ImportError: No module named 'models.flownet2_pytorch'

cd vid2vid
cd vid2vid
/workspace/AI/vid2vid

freeze
!pip freeze
absl-py==0.2.2
astor==0.6.2
backcall==0.1.0
bleach==1.5.0
certifi==2018.10.15
channelnorm-cuda==0.0.0
chardet==3.0.4
cmake==3.12.0
correlation-cuda==0.0.0
cycler==0.10.0
decorator==4.3.0
defusedxml==0.5.0
dlib==19.16.0
dominate==2.3.4
entrypoints==0.2.3
future==0.16.0
gast==0.2.0
grpcio==1.13.0
h5py==2.8.0
horovod==0.12.1
html5lib==0.9999999
idna==2.7
ipykernel==5.1.0
ipython==7.1.1
ipython-genutils==0.2.0
ipywidgets==7.4.2
jedi==0.13.1
Jinja2==2.10
jsonschema==2.6.0
jupyter==1.0.0
jupyter-client==5.2.3
jupyter-console==6.0.0
jupyter-core==4.4.0
Keras==2.2.4
Keras-Applications==1.0.6
Keras-Preprocessing==1.0.5
kiwisolver==1.0.1
llvmlite==0.23.2
Markdown==2.6.11
MarkupSafe==1.0
matplotlib==3.0.1
mistune==0.8.4
mock==2.0.0
mpi4py==3.0.0
nbconvert==5.4.0
nbformat==4.4.0
nltk==3.2.5
notebook==5.7.0
numba==0.38.1
numpy==1.15.4
nvidia-dali==0.1.1
opencv-python==3.4.3.18
pandas==0.23.0
pandocfilters==1.4.2
parso==0.3.1
pbr==4.0.4
pexpect==4.6.0
pickleshare==0.7.5
Pillow==5.3.0
prometheus-client==0.4.2
prompt-toolkit==2.0.7
protobuf==3.6.0
psutil==5.4.6
ptyprocess==0.6.0
Pygments==2.2.0
pyparsing==2.3.0
python-dateutil==2.7.3
python-speech-features==0.6
pytz==2018.5
PyYAML==3.13
pyzmq==17.1.2
qtconsole==4.4.2
requests==2.20.1
resample2d-cuda==0.0.0
resampy==0.2.1
scikit-learn==0.20.0
scipy==1.1.0
Send2Trash==1.5.0
six==1.11.0
sklearn==0.0
tensorboard==1.8.0
tensorflow-gpu==1.8.0
termcolor==1.1.0
terminado==0.8.1
testpath==0.4.2
torch==0.4.1
torchvision==0.2.1
tornado==5.1.1
tqdm==4.23.4
traitlets==4.3.2
urllib3==1.24.1
wcwidth==0.1.7
Werkzeug==0.14.1
widgetsnbextension==3.4.2
```

Any idea?

Comment: Please share the code where you are importing the library. Also, the exact error message

Comment: Please boild down the code which exhibits your problem to a minimal verifyable example and share that in your question. The code is much more important thant all your environment. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask